# How can I create an expanding buffer?

Tags: cat, buffer

I want to be able to scroll back through all of the output for each session in terminal.

When using `cat` on large files, for example, there could be hundreds, or even thousands, of lines (I write a lot of things in a lot of files).

Is there a way, without using `setterm --resize`, `more`, or `less`, to increase the buffer size on an "as-needed" basis, automatically OR manually?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the terminal emulator you’re using.

In GNOME Terminal, yes, this is possible: in your profile preferences, make sure “Limit scrollback to:” in the “Scrolling” section is unchecked:

[image: GNOME Terminal preferences screen showing the Scrolling section, with the “Limit scrollback to” entry highlighted]

Kitty on the other hand doesn’t allow an unlimited scrollback buffer size to be set, and having a huge scrollback buffer [isn’t recommended](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#scrollback); but you can keep a separate paged scrollback buffer (accessible in your pager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you are solving the wrong problem. More precisely, by using `cat` even for large files when it would make more sense to use `less`, you are creating a problem for yourself that you don't need to have.

Just get into the habit of using `less`.  With the `-F` (`--quit-if-one-screen`) option, it will automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed in the terminal without scrolling.  So it acts like `cat` for short files, and as a pager (with forward and back movement, and built-in search, etc) for long files.  As a bonus, by habitually using less instead of cat, you avoid the risk of messing up your terminal by accidentally cat-ing a binary file.

This can be made the default either by setting an alias like `alias less='less -F'` or by setting the LESS environment variable (e.g. `export LESS=-F`).

This can, of course, be combined with other less options, e.g. I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LESS=-MFRqx4ij3
```

---

BTW, I set my terminal apps to have a scrollback buffer of 10,000 lines.  That's enough almost all of the time, anything that far back in my scroll buffer is rarely relevant to whatever I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243445/bash-command-to-change-size-of-bash-window

The answer by "Pillpusher" works perfectly for what I'm after. It's simply a matter of changing the numbers to suit my needs:

"*The resize command works to change the size of the window, but you may

experience some strange things if you don't also tell the terminal to
use the whole area. This is what I use, and it works well.*"

```
    `#!/bin/bash`
    `resize -s 33 100`
    `stty rows 33`
    `stty cols 100`
```